# JavaScript - How to check for URL with specific domain name?

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

How would I use JavaScript to look for a specific domain name and then return true if its the one I am looking for, or false if it is not the URL that I am looking for. In my example a user types a URL in an input box, JavaScript checks if it is a specific domain such as https://example.com and then redirects the user to that page. If they type another URL without the https://example.com, JavaScript will return false and show an error message. If a user types the URL https://example.com/join/1234 I just wish to check the main domain. The code I have so far is below. I have tried using regex butI dont know how I can make it only check the domain name -> https://example.com .

```
 <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-5"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id = "start-call" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-duration="900" data-aos-delay="2000" type="button" style="margin: 160px;width: 135px;" onclick = "goToCall()" >Start Call</button></div>


 function isDomainURL(str){
  regexp =  /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/;
    if (regexp.test(str)){

    return true;

    }else{

    return false:

    }

 }

 if (isDomainURL(document.getElementById('input-01').value) == true)
    {
        window.location = document.getElementById('input-01').value;
    }
    else
    {
        swal({
            title: "Invalid URL",
            text: "Thats was an invalid DropCall URL.",
            icon: "error",
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code of the `isDomainURL` method and report what the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the usage of a URL object for this purpose.

```js
const url = new URL('https://example.com/my-path');

console.log(url.host);
```

It's way simpler that usage of regexp.

Please keep in mind that relative URLs are also acceptable, thus, I would recommend checking if the protocol is a part of the string.

Comment: How would I check to see if url.host is https://example.com? Then return true or false?

Comment: if (url.host === 'example.com') { ... }

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that there is another property on an URL instance, `hostname`. Let's assume  `localhost:3000` as URL. `host` is equal to `localhost:3000` and `hostname` is equal to `localhost`.